# How to edit Mongo connection string?

Tags: mongodb, connection-string, mongodb-replica-set

After converting the **standalone** to the **replica set** the connection string has not been modified, but it works fine.

If I type `mongo <server IP>` the connection string is still the same as it was before the conversion `mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb`.

How to convert it into `mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/admin?replicaSet=myRepl&readPreference=primaryPreferred`?

I have tried to set *read preferences* with `db.getMongo().setReadPref('primaryPreferred')`, but the string is still the same.

Thanks!

Comment: I understood that you want to use **mongo CLI** `mongo` to connect to a replica-set using read-preference? Which of the strings worked as command-line argument?

Answer (score 0):

Try your connection string without `admin` (or even without the standard port `:27017`). Then it's pretty much the same like in the
[Doc's for connection string with read-preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#read-preference-options):

```
mongodb://db0.example.com,db1.example.com,db2.example.com/?replicaSet=myRepl&readPreference=secondary&maxStalenessSeconds=120
```

Passing it as argument **within double-quotes** to the *mongo shell* (see the [CLI syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/index.html#syntax))you could type like following on the command-line (terminal):

```sh
mongo "mongodb://mongodb0.example.com.local:27017,mongodb1.example.com.local:27017,mongodb2.example.com.local:27017/?replicaSet=replA"
```